# Mockito's `thenReturn` is not working for data class field

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

So i have a class:

```
data class LoyaltyVoucher(
    val voucherNumber: String,
...
)
```

And in instrumental test i want to mock this field:

```
val serverVoucher = Mockito.mock(LoyaltyVoucher::class.java)
Mockito.`when`(serverVoucher.voucherNumber).thenReturn("some number")
```

But `serverVoucher.voucherNumber` gives me `null` always. For some reason if i create getter function manually it works:

```
fun getVoucherNumberTest() : String {
    return voucherNumber
}
```

...

```
val serverVoucher = Mockito.mock(LoyaltyVoucher::class.java)
Mockito.`when`(serverVoucher.getVoucherNumberTest()).thenReturn("some number")
```

and calling `serverVoucher.getVoucherNumberTest()` returns "some number".

What can cause this problem?

Using `mockito-inline` for data classes: `"com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito-inline:2.28.3"`

**EDIT:** You can also answer with common practices of testing data class, i researched a bit, and saw that some developers insist that it's not a good idea to mock those at all

Comment: not sure why you would want to mock this to begin with, what is wrong with just creating an instance of it with your own data that you want to use in your test ?

Comment: i'm currently rewriting tests from Java to Kotlin, and although your suggestion can work, i wanted to maintain the same way of mocking data as before. Despite all of that, why is this even works in such way? @a_local_nobody

Comment: yeah your question is interesting, i was just wondering if you might be overcomplicating it. perhaps mockito just can't target the generated getter and setter that the data class is making ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody, i guess you are right, but i'm curious of whether there is a solution expect for just setting this value directly

Comment: to be fair, if you went from a java class where you had to write getters and setters yourself to now using a data class which is doing it for you, you're not really going from the java way of doing it to the kotlin way of doing it (because here, the kotlin way would be a class, not a data class)

Comment: but since data class is basically just a final class with some overrides it can be treated as such, right? So your suggestion is that setting value on mocked object directly is a more common way of testing data class?

Comment: if `LoyaltyVoucher` is just holding data it gets from somewhere else, i wouldn't test it. if it needs to have specific values, then something else should be giving it those values, which you can test (like a formatter, etc.). but if it's just a pojo, i wouldn't test it. i just don't see the point in doing that

Comment: I'm not testing this class, i'm testing a fuction which should give me the same result as this mocked class

Comment: yeah, then i would just make `val expectedResult = LoyaltyVoucher(voucherNumber = "foo"...)` and then assert that either `expectedResult.voucherNumber` = something else or just assert that  `expectedResult` is the same as something else, but that's my take on it

Comment: thanks for the input! I'm having same suggestions, seems like i will go that route

Comment: cool. also worth saying that nothing you've posted here so far shows why it can't just be a normal unit test, but i'm sure you have a reason for making an instrumented test

Comment: oh, i just mentioned the type because i thought this can be a part of the problem :) it has purpose to be instrumental @a_local_nobody

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was decided to just create an object and not mock it. Since for this test there is no extra use for this class that requires mock